# JAXB enoding issue when marshalling to System.out

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jaxb

I'm trying to print to console my java bean, unmarshalled from a HTTP response. I have issues with encoding.
Here's some part of response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Response>
   <ErrorMsg>Ä°ÅŸleminizi ...</ErrorMsg>
</Response>
```

My method is:

```
public void printToConsole() {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
                Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.marshal(this, System.out);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

By viewing bean values with debugger, they're shown correctly in debugger's pop-up(Eclipse IDE)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that by using default console settings, it will not be able to print the UTF-8 characters properly. Make sure the console you use to display the output is also encoded in UTF-8. For example, in Eclipse , you need to go to

> Run Configuration > Common > Encoding

and select UTF-8 or relevant encoding.

[image]

Comment: Phew. That was easy :). Using Eclipse for 3+ years and never saw this tab on run configurations. Thanks

Comment: @braincell Please accept the answer if it helped to resolve your problem. Accepting the answer helps others facing the same problem.